# Is there a square brush tip in sculpting mode

Tags: modeling, sculpting

Pretty much as title. Is there a way to make the brush tip a square instead of a circle in sculpting mode?

[image]

I suppose this should be a very trivial thing but I really couldn't find the option:

[image]

Comment: I haven't heard of such a brush but you could do is paint with a b&w texture with a square shape

Comment: @Emir I assume there would be two different options, one for brush tip and one for texture (like photoshop and every other painting softwares). But it seems in Blender they are the same thing...? I'm not so sure.

Comment: "every other painting softwares" - since Blender is no painting software, it might as well be different.